# Making An Email Address With My Domain | Postfix & Sendgrid

Tags: email, postfix

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and I can't seem to find any clear instructions on what I really need to get an email address set up with my website.

I've installed Postfix and configured it to have all of the email addresses I will need and have an SMTP (Sendgrid) set up to send email for me.

My question is what else do I need to set up an email address? Am I even going in the right direction? I've heard of Dovecot but I don't know if I need to use it along with an SMTP.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and Nginx + Passenger.

Comment: Does your ISP provide mail service? Some charge extra, over and above the cost of domain registration, to provide mail service.

Comment: @K7AAY I don't think so, I'm using Digital Ocean.

Comment: Suggest you ask them.

Comment: @Lama, I never did solve it.

Comment: I don't see it as an offered service at https://www.digitalocean.com

Comment: @K7AAY I don't think it would be anyway unless it was a one-click option like they do for other languages. But, that would be an unnecessary cost for me. I'm using a blank Ubuntu VPS, they even have tutorials on using Postfix, I could just never get it to work.